# Rotate a group of rectangles around their common center

Tags: java, javafx

I have a few rectangles that I assign rotation one by one `((javafx.scene.shape.Rectangle) shape).rotateProperty().bind(rotate);`
For example, 45 degrees
[image]

[image]

My rectangle rotates around its center. Please tell me how to make the enemy a few right-angles around their common center.
[image]

To get something like this
[image]

`this.rotate.addListener((obs, old, fresh) -> {`
`for (VObject vObject : children ) {`
`vObject.rotate.set(this.rotate.get());`
`}`
`});` 
This is how I add rotation. How can I specify the angle

**Update:** I used the advice below and now I set the rotation individually for each rectangle. (The selection is still a bit wrong)

```
            this.rotate.addListener((obs, old, fresh) -> {
            Rotate groupRotate = new Rotate(rotate.get(),
                    this.x.getValue().doubleValue() + this.width.getValue().doubleValue() / 2 ,
                    this.y.getValue().doubleValue() + this.height.getValue().doubleValue() / 2);
            for (VObject vObject : children ) {
                vObject.getShape().getTransforms().clear();
                vObject.getShape().getTransforms().add(groupRotate);
            }
        });
```

[image]
[image]
But now the axis also rotates depending on the rotation.

[image]

Can I set the rotation to the rectangles without turning the coordinate axis?

Answer (score 5):

If you put all rectangles into a common `Group`, you can rotate them at once:

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Group;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
import javafx.scene.shape.Rectangle;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class RotateAllApplication extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
        BorderPane root = new BorderPane();

        // the common group
        Group group = new Group();
        group.getChildren().addAll(new Rectangle(10, 10, 80, 40), //
                new Rectangle(110, 10, 80, 40), //
                new Rectangle(10, 110, 80, 40), //
                new Rectangle(110, 110, 80, 40));

        // rotate the group instead of each rectangle
        group.setRotate(45.0);

        root.setCenter(group);

        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root, 600, 400));
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Application.launch(args);
    }
}
```

**Update**: If you don't want to create a parent `Group` object, you can apply the same rotation transformation to each child instead. While `Node#setRotate(double)` always rotates around the center of the node, adding a transformation to `Node#getTransforms()` is more general and not restricted to simple rotations.

The following statement will apply a rotation around the point `(100.0/100.0)` of the parent coordinate system to all children in the list:

```
childrenList.forEach(child -> child.getTransforms().add(Transform.rotate(45.0, 100.0, 100.0)));
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But I can not add my rectangles to the group.

Comment: `this.rotate.addListener((obs, old, fresh) -> {`
`for (VObject vObject : children ) {`
`vObject.rotate.set(this.rotate.get());`
`}`
`});` 
This is how I add rotation. How can I specify the angle

Comment: Then you should probably use a `Rotation` transformation on each child. I'm going to update my answer.

Comment: More thanks for the reply. I apply the usual transformation because after that I move the rectangles. When I set the rotation through `rotateProperty()`, then everything works correctly. But if I set the rotation through the `getTransforms()`, then I have an offset of the coordinate axis and the rectangle moves incorrectly. I already created a topic for this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53293315/javafx-rotation

Answer (score 4):

Use a `Rotate` transform and specify the appropriate pivot point:

```
@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws IOException {
    Pane pane = new Pane();
    pane.setPrefSize(600, 600);
    Rectangle[] rects = new Rectangle[4];
    for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 2; j++) {
            Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(100 + i * 200, 100 + j * 100, 150, 50);
            rects[i * 2 + j] = rect;
            pane.getChildren().add(rect);
        }
    }

    Slider slider = new Slider(0, 360, 0);

    double minX = Double.POSITIVE_INFINITY;
    double minY = Double.POSITIVE_INFINITY;
    double maxX = Double.NEGATIVE_INFINITY;
    double maxY = Double.NEGATIVE_INFINITY;

    Rotate rotate = new Rotate();

    // find pivot point     
    for (Rectangle rect : rects) {
        double val = rect.getX();
        if (minX > val) {
            minX = val;
        }
        val += rect.getWidth();
        if (maxX < val) {
            maxX = val;
        }

        val = rect.getY();
        if (minY > val) {
            minY = val;
        }
        val += rect.getHeight();
        if (maxY < val) {
            maxY = val;
        }

        rect.getTransforms().add(rotate);
    }
    rotate.setPivotX(0.5 * (maxX + minX));
    rotate.setPivotY(0.5 * (maxY + minY));
    rotate.angleProperty().bind(slider.valueProperty());
    Scene scene = new Scene(new VBox(10, pane, slider));
    primaryStage.setScene(scene);
    primaryStage.sizeToScene();
    primaryStage.show();
}
```

If you're planing to apply multiple transformations, you may need to adjust the code for finding the pivot point to use transforms for calculating the bounds...