# Javafx affine transformation

Tags: java, javafx

I have 2 rectangles with coordinates Rectangle1 (x = 100, y = 100, width = 200, height = 50) and Rectangle2 (x = 100, y = 200, width = 200, height = 50). How to set an affine transformation for them so that they rotate around the center of these rectangles (point x = 200, y = 175). For example, at 45 degrees:

[image]

[image]

I set the rotation individually

```
        this.rotate.addListener((obs, old, fresh) -> {
        Rotate groupRotate = new Rotate(rotate.get(),
                this.x.getValue().doubleValue() + this.width.getValue().doubleValue() / 2 ,
                this.y.getValue().doubleValue() + this.height.getValue().doubleValue() / 2);
        for (VObject vObject : children ) {
            vObject.getShape().getTransforms().clear();
            vObject.getShape().getTransforms().add(groupRotate);
        }
    });
```

But now the axis also rotates depending on the rotation.
[image]

Can I set the rotation to the rectangles without turning the coordinate axis?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Rotate a group of rectangles around their common center](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53410764/rotate-a-group-of-rectangles-around-their-common-center)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Add both rectangles to a common [`Node`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/Node.html)
2. Create a [`Rotate`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/transform/Rotate.html) object
3. Set the angle and pivot point of the rotation
4. Apply the rotation via `node.getTransforms.add(rotate)`

*Edit*: Regarding your updated question about preserving the axis when moving the rotated object around: Add each rotated object into an unrotated container. Now move this container instead of its contents.

Comment: This method is not suitable as it together with the figure rotates the coordinate axis of the rectangle

Comment: Then please update your question and add further constraints to your problem. If you don't want to add the two rects to a common container, you can still apply two different transformations to each of them. Note: The pivot point of the rotation can be outside of the bounds of each rect.

Comment: I already apply a transformation for each rectangle separately. But at the same time, if I, for example, specify a rotation angle of 90 degrees, then the coordinate axis rotates along with the rectangles. Can I rotate the rectangle and not rotate the coordinate axis? In more detail here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53410764/rotate-a-group-of-rectangles-around-their-common-center

Comment: Sorry, I don't fully understand the problem. If it is about the coordinate axis, please update your question.

Comment: I make a graphic editor. In which you can draw for example rectangles and move them. Now I added the rotation of these rectangles using `getTransforms ()`. Now, if I set the rotation 90 degrees, then along with my rectangle its coordinate axis also rotates. And when I draw such a rectangle up, it starts moving to the right.

Comment: Again: *Please update your question!* Others might not read these comments, so please include these important information about what you're trying to achieve in your question!

Comment: Updated my question

Comment: If you want to rotate your rectangles, the best way is adding them into the `Group`. Rotating the group won't change the axis.

Comment: Because of the features of the application, I can not combine them into a group, I can set the rotation only individually.

Comment: @A1exNS then give each of them an individual container. No group. See my updated answer.

Comment: I am new to javafx, could you tell me how to do this?

Comment: Sebastian S Thank you very much for your time, added the group and everything worked out.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to use Analytics Geometry, then you **should** try to use grouping objects (in the code below is the controller class, and part of the `fxml` file).

```
public class Controller {

    @FXML
    private Group groupTwoRects;
    @FXML
    private Rectangle rectOne;
    @FXML
    private Rectangle rectTwo;
    @FXML
    private Button btnClick;

    @FXML
    public void btnClick() {
        groupTwoRects.setRotate(groupTwoRects.getRotate() + 45.0);
        System.out.println(rectOne.getRotationAxis());
        System.out.println(rectTwo.getRotationAxis());
    }
}

<AnchorPane prefHeight="600.0" prefWidth="600.0">
        <children>
            <Button fx:id="btnClick" layoutX="14.0" layoutY="161.0" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#btnClick" text="Click" AnchorPane.bottomAnchor="14.0" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="14.0" />
        <Group fx:id="groupTwoRects" layoutX="62.0" layoutY="76.0" rotate="-53.1">
           <children>
              <Rectangle fx:id="rectOne" arcHeight="5.0" arcWidth="5.0" fill="DODGERBLUE" height="53.0" stroke="BLACK" strokeType="INSIDE" width="179.0" />
              <Rectangle fx:id="rectTwo" arcHeight="5.0" arcWidth="5.0" fill="DODGERBLUE" height="53.0" layoutY="95.0" stroke="BLACK" strokeType="INSIDE" width="179.0" />
           </children>
        </Group>
        </children>
</AnchorPane>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I can not use the group